# How do I make quickly apps install into /opt?

Tags: application-development, quickly

I've created the 'hello world' example using Quickly and created a debian package using `quickly package`. This package installs the app into `/usr/share` and `/usr/bin`.

However, the [packaging requirements at developer.ubuntu.com](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages) say that the package has to install into `/opt`. How do I convert my quickly application so that it conforms with the requirements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a new command to generate a proper package. It will also ask you to create a launchpad project and set up everything you need:

```
quickly submitubuntu
```

Comment: You can also try it on a local package by running `quickly package --extras`